# One RACSignal used at one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a test example with one button. When user presses the button is called RAC_request and request is executing. If user presses this button a many times for a short time, many requests will be execute asynchronously. I want to create logic to previously signal cancelled when new request is executing by **Reactive Cocoa**. I know that exists `switchToLatest` in **Reactive Cocoa**, but I can't do that logic work correctly. How do this by RAC?

Answer (score 1):

if user presses the button a many times for a short time, you can use `throttle` to set the time. if a interval times have many nextValue, it only take newest. also you can use switchToLatest. There is a easy example,  i hole that would be useful for you.

```
[button.rac_command execute:nil];

button.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc]initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {

    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        [subscriber sendNext:@"TestSignal"];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{

        }];

    }];
}];

[[[button.rac_command.executionSignals throttle:0.5] switchToLatest]subscribeNext:^(id x) {

    NSLog(@"%@", x);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I have a bit another situation. I have to call request when I get applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, it's just a request which update user timezone. And if user so often hide/show application with bad internet connection current updateRequest should cancels previously request. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko ry to create a RACSignal in appDelegate, and activate it in applicationDidBecomeActive. Then you can deal with the signal by switchToLatest or throttle

Comment: sorry, but I spent a lot of time and cannot do this :( Can you show some code for my case? It will save a lot of time for me!